# BFBC2 "Unable to login" when entering serial number

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2, origin

So I installed this "Origin" crap, bought, downloaded and installed Battlefield: Bad Company 2.

Now, when I launch the game and login with the same account I use to buy it in Origin, I'm asked to enter my serial number, which I do, but after hitting the submit button I get the "Unable to login" error, every, single, time.

I can't seem to find out where to enter it on the Origin or EA site, so how am I supposed to register my game?

Edit: Okay, so I found the "Redeem product code" in the Origin app, but now when I try to login to BFBC2 with the same account it still asks for the serial, but then says it's already in use, what the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching this error message on the EA support center gets me [**this article.**](http://support.ea.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5395/kw/Unable%20to%20login/showhome/true) In a nutshell:

1. Turn off 'remember password' and log in again.
2. Delete the BFBC2 folder that should be located in your Documents folder and log in again.
3. [Open a ticket if all else fails.](http://support.ea.com/app/ask)

Comment: Hasn't solved the issue, but I'm talking with them via the live chat on their site now, hopefully they can resolve this issue.

Comment: Okay, talked with the nice live support person and they were able to solve the issue, whatever it was. Thanks for your reply though, will accept it as you're the only person to have replied.

Comment: @Cupcake Consider sharing the solution with the community then! _What_ did fix your issue?

Comment: I have no idea, like I stated in my comment "they were able to solve the issue _whatever it was_.", they asked for my information, I gave it to them, they then told me to try again and the issue was corrected.

Comment: @Cupcake Thank you, that means they flipped a switch on their side :)